# Prolog - pairs that are not related

Tags: prolog

```
parent(kresimir, jasna).
parent(kresimir, darko).
parent(vesna, darko).
parent(darko, vigor).
parent(darko, goran).
parent(vigor, ruzica).
parent(vigor, snjezana).
parent(mario, nenad).

ancestor(X, Y) :-
    parent(X, Y).

ancestor(X, Y) :-
    parent(X, Z),
    ancestor(Z, Y).


related(X, Y) :-
    parent(X,Y);
    parent(Y,X).
related(X, Y) :-
    X \= Y,
    ancestor(Z, X),
    ancestor(Z, Y).
```

This is my prolog file, what i need is to find all pairs of people that are not related, and i have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way get all the people first.

```
person(X) :- parent(X, _).
person(X) :- parent(_, X).
```

Then use [`setof/3`](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node98.html#subsec.l11.setof) to get a list of people without duplicates:

```
setof(X, person(X), People)
```

and collect all pairs from that:

```
pair_of_people(X,Y) :-
    setof(P, person(P), People),
    member(X, People),
    member(Y, People),
    X \= Y.
```

This, by the way, produces "mirror" pairs: both `(X,Y)` and `(Y,X)` for all `X` and `Y`. You can do better with an adapted version of `member` that many Prologs support. Check out your Prolog manual.

Finally, filter out the pairs that are `related`:

```
unrelated(X,Y) :-
    pair_of_people(X,Y),
    not(related(X,Y)).
```